Handicapped person wishing for Java mouseEntered method to show dialogpane ONLY if hovering more than a set time (1 or 2 seconds)
My handicapped friend wants to be able to simply hover over some of the components in the Java UI project I'm building such that pressing down or clicking is unnecessary.
Since there would be a dozen or so components exhibiting the same capabilities, he doesn't want dialog panes unwittingly opening all over the place while moving his hand horizontally causing the pointer to slide across the monitor.
Short of some assistive technology built in Java Swing which I'm not aware of, I would appreciate if someone could suggest a way to implement such a scheme.
I've thought or/and tried the following:

Conceptually, created a timer loop with a break or yield condition that would programmatically tell the mouseExited method to cancel
Use the SwingTimer without success
Since the time span between mouseEntered and mouseExited would be quite short, I thought of using the Java time-stamp when hovering starts and finishes, and if less or equal to its chosen length, then cancel, however, if the selected set-time is exceeded then the dialog would open as expected.


Hover over them to do what? Get help on them? Activate them? How would you tell the difference between a user hovering for that purpose vs. a user who simply stopped moving their mouse, for whatever reason?

"Such that pressing down or clicking is unnecessary" implies hovering activates them. You don't tell the difference between a user who just stopped their mouse vs actually hovered, you make this an option. It's not an uncommon accessibility feature.

Take a JFormattedTextField as many are the case, when the pointer or I-Beam hovers on it, the mouseEntered method detects it and causes my custom dialog to open. What I want to do is to use the time-length in hovering to fork off two possibilities:


Wait 1 or 2 seconds and exit the process



Proceed to open the custom dialog


My handicapped friend is unable to press down or click, so the only choice for him is what I suggested above. Jason, you say "it's not an uncommon accessibility feature", so how do I go about implementing this method?

Every JButton in your GUI has to implement this feature, including the JButtons in a JOptionPane.  Your mouseEntered method saves the current time and checks for a new current time every 100 ms using a Swing timer.  When the difference in time is 2 seconds, you execute the JButton ActionListener.  Your mouseExited method clears the current time.

I was answering the question with facts and citations.  I  voted to reopen.

@GilbertLeBlanc I've also voted to re-open, as I feel this is a valuable question, and I'd love to see the answer from your comment as a "proper" answer.

Does this help? How to Support Assistive Technologies

I created a simple example.  When you hover over the Submit button for two seconds, a JOptionPane will appear. You will have to left click on the OK button on the JOptionPane to close it.
I created a HoverListener class to handle hovering.  For each and every JButton in your GUI, you will create an instance of the HoverListener and an ActionListener.  The ActionListener will need a reference to the HoverListener to work properly.
The HoverListener uses a MouseListener (MouseAdapter) and a Java Timer to set a two second timer.  If you mouseExited before the two seconds are up, the timer stops.  If you left click on the JButton, the timer stops.
Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the HoverListener an inner class so I could post the code as one block.  Put the HoverListener in its own file for your GUI project.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MouseEnteredExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MouseEnteredExample());
    }

    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Mouse Entered Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(25, 100, 25, 100));

        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        HoverListener listener = new HoverListener(button, 2000); // 2000 ms = 2 sec
        button.addMouseListener(listener);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                listener.resetEnteredTime();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                        "The Submit button was either clicked "
                        + "or hovered", "Example",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);

        return panel;
    }

    public class HoverListener extends MouseAdapter {

        private long enteredTime;
        private final long duration;

        private final JButton button;

        public HoverListener(JButton button, long duration) {
            this.button = button;
            this.duration = duration;
            this.enteredTime = 0L;
        }
        
        public void resetEnteredTime() {
            this.enteredTime = 0L;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            this.enteredTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Timer timer = new Timer((int) (duration / 20L), new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    if (enteredTime > 0L) {
                        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long difference = currentTime - enteredTime;
                        if (difference >= duration) {
                            enteredTime = 0L;
                            stopTimer(event);
                            button.doClick(300);
                        }
                    } else {
                        stopTimer(event);
                    }
                }
                
                private void stopTimer(ActionEvent event) {
                    Timer timer = (Timer) event.getSource();
                    timer.stop();
                }
            });

            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            this.enteredTime = 0L;
        }

    }

}

Edited to add:
I made the HoverListener an abstract class so it's no longer limited to JButtons.  You specify the action on a successful hover.
Here's the complete runnable code.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MouseEnteredExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MouseEnteredExample());
    }

    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Mouse Entered Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(25, 100, 25, 100));

        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        HoverListener listener = new HoverListener(2000) {  // 2000 ms = 2 sec
            @Override
            public void hoverPerformed() {
                button.doClick(300);
            }   
        }; 
        button.addMouseListener(listener);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                listener.resetEnteredTime();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                        "The Submit button was either clicked "
                        + "or hovered", "Example",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);

        return panel;
    }

    public abstract class HoverListener extends MouseAdapter {

        private long enteredTime;
        private final long duration;

        public HoverListener(long duration) {
            this.duration = duration;
            this.enteredTime = 0L;
        }
        
        public void resetEnteredTime() {
            this.enteredTime = 0L;
        }
        
        public abstract void hoverPerformed();

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            this.enteredTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Timer timer = new Timer((int) (duration / 20L), new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    if (enteredTime > 0L) {
                        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long difference = currentTime - enteredTime;
                        if (difference >= duration) {
                            enteredTime = 0L;
                            stopTimer(event);
                            hoverPerformed();
                        }
                    } else {
                        stopTimer(event);
                    }
                }
                
                private void stopTimer(ActionEvent event) {
                    Timer timer = (Timer) event.getSource();
                    timer.stop();
                }
            });

            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            this.enteredTime = 0L;
        }

    }

}


Why do you configure the timer to invoke the action listener 20 times, to perform a check for the actual elapsed time, instead of just one time after the intended duration?

A straight-forward implementation would be public abstract class HoverListener extends MouseAdapter { private final Timer timer; public HoverListener(int duration) { timer = new Timer(duration, ev -> hoverPerformed()); timer.setRepeats(false); } public void resetEnteredTime() { timer.stop(); } public abstract void hoverPerformed(); @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { timer.restart(); } @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { timer.stop(); } }

@Holger: What happens using a one time Timer when the user mouse exits or left clicks the JButton before the two seconds are up?

@GilbertLeBlanc the timer.stop() calls will do their job. There’s one in the mouseExited method and one in the resetEnteredTime() method which will be called by the actionPerformed method in the answer’s code. I’d probably change the name but it fulfills its purpose.
